# How to use If else statements in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: java, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

1. Question:

I have 8 buttons like (discover,news,people,videos,sport,tech,offbeat,ents). so i want to click on any one or more buttons. actually i don't know what to use here, i was thinking if else will work. need some help. Here there is a problem which i feel is, all buttons have same class name so how to use if else for this type of issue.

```html
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn btn-default button ng-scope ng-binding" type="button" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="addTag(category.text)">discover</button>
<button class="btn btn-default button ng-scope ng-binding" type="button" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="addTag(category.text)">news</button>
<button class="btn btn-default button ng-scope ng-binding" type="button" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="addTag(category.text)">people</button>
<button class="btn btn-default button ng-scope ng-binding" type="button" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="addTag(category.text)">videos</button>
<button class="btn btn-default button ng-scope ng-binding" type="button" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="addTag(category.text)">sport</button>
<button class="btn btn-default button ng-scope ng-binding" type="button" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="addTag(category.text)">tech</button>
<button class="btn btn-default button ng-scope ng-binding" type="button" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="addTag(category.text)">offbeat</button>
<button class="btn btn-default button ng-scope ng-binding" type="button" ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-click="addTag(category.text)">ents</button>
</div>
```

```
if(!driver.findElement(By.className("default button ")).isSelected())
    {
      driver.findElement(By.className("default button")).sendKeys("discover");
    }
    else 
    {
        driver.findElement(By.className("default button")).sendKeys("news");
    }
```

2. Question:

I have 8 tags as drop downs like (discover,news,people,videos,sport,tech,offbeat,ents). so i want to select only any one tag. how do i use if else statements for this...

```html
   <div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon title">Category</span>
<input class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-editable" typeahead="category.text for category in categories | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" ng-model="article.category" placeholder="Enter Category">
<ul class="dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope" ng-style="{display: isOpen()&&'block' || 'none', top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}" typeahead-popup="" matches="matches" active="activeIdx" select="select(activeIdx)" query="query" position="position" style="display: none; top: 34px; left: 165.05px;"> </ul>
</div>
```

thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please share your HTML code. Thanks

Comment: Do not post two questions in one. This makes it next to impossible to actually mark any one answer as the answer to the question.

Comment: Added HTML code @JuhiSaxena

Comment: The both questions are related to one issue so I have posted into one. @evolutionxbox

Comment: @vamc Is your intention to click on the button based on the text you provide as input ?

Comment: @vamc you are saying the buttons are in drop down but in above code it does not seem so.

Comment: @JuhiSaxena
I haven't added the code for question 2, sry for that. The code is related to first question only. Thanks

Comment: @JuhiSaxena i have added the html code for 2question as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this kind of logic, which will click a button based on the name you provide as input to the method.

```
public void clickButton(String buttonName) throws Exception{

    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/button"));
           for(int i=0;i<buttons.size();i++){
                String buttonText= buttons.get(i).getText();
                if (buttonText.equals(buttonName)) {
                     buttons.get(i).click();
                     int flag =1;
                 }
            }

       if (!flag == 1)
        throw new Exception("The desired button is not present.");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but this code accepts only one button which i can enter the button name at "string buttonname" where i can use xpath of single button which i need, if i need all 8 buttons randomly, i cannot use this code.

Comment: do you want to click all the buttons at once ? or you want a method to  click any of the buttons randomly ?

Comment: I have two cases like, need all buttons in one case and I want a method to click randomly in one case. Thanks

Comment: you can click only one button at a time manually or through selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method By.xpath and xpath text()

```
By.xpath("//div/button[contains(@class, 'default') and contains(@class, 'button') and text()='discover']")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply !!
The above code which you have replied, is not working at all. the code is not recognised at all and i assume that by the above code, only discover button will be clicked but if i need to click more other button also i cannot. If i need to click only on discover button then I can use directly the xpath right. Actually i want random buttons should be clicked not one or not all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To click all the buttons, make a method like this:

```
public void clickAllButtons()
{
    //finds the div element, then grabs all button tags inside of the div
    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElement(By.className("btn-group")).findElements(By.tagName("button"));
    for(int i=0;i<buttons.size();i++)
    {
        buttons.get(i).click();
    }
}
```

To get a random index clicked, use a method like this:

```
public void clickRandomButton() throws Exception
{
    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/button"));
    Random rn = new Random();
    int rand = rn.nextInt(buttons.size()-1);
    buttons.get(rand).click();
}
```

if you want a method where you click multiple buttons based on the text you input, then ill do a slight alteration to HemChe's answer like so:

```
public void clickButtonsByNames(ArrayList<String> buttonNames) throws Exception\
{
    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/button"));
    for(String buttonName : buttonNames)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<buttons.size();i++)
        {
            String buttonText= buttons.get(i).getText();
            if (buttonText.equals(buttonName)) 
            {
                buttons.get(i).click();
                int flag =1;
            } 
        }
    }
    if (!flag == 1)
        throw new Exception("The desired button is not present.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its very much helpful, but I have a problem with clicking on all buttons, the code which you have above clicks all buttons in the website, so what i need to do to click only 8 buttons, if i give i=8, the code clicks on 8th button only !! can you please help this out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again !! In the first line of code in "Clickallbuttons" /***findElements****/ shows as error due to there is no driver for that. Can you please look at it. Thanks !!

Comment: driver is whatever your driver in your selenium code is called. such as your IEDriver or ChromeDriver, etc. I compiled it fine in my workspace with an IEDriver. Can you give a more specific error if you are using the correct driveR?

Comment: it should be "List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElement(" not "List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements("

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was my typing mistake. Thanks again. It works now.

Comment: Not a problem! i hope that is the solution you are looking for!